# Create button in rendered template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-templates

Let me get straight to the point :). In my project I'm rendering an template, with jquery-tmpl, like this:

```
box = $.tmpl('<div> [....] <button></button> [....] </div>')
```

If I insert `box` in the DOM, nice JQuery buttons show up. According to the DOM (inspected with Chrome) the `buttons` have already been converted to `jquery-ui` buttons.

The question: I want to modify these buttons, but - after trying for two hours - I can't figure out how to. I figured

```
$('button', box).button({'icons' : {'primary' : 'icon name'}})
```

for example, would do the trick, but it doesn't. How do I modify my buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryUI generally follows a pattern of updating widgets after they've been initialized on DOM elements:

`$("#foo").button("option", "optionname", value);`

So to [update the button's icon](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#option-icons) after init, you'd do this:

`$("button", box).button("option", "icons", {primary:'icon-name'});`